# OnClick - How to add first, last and active ClassName for each slide in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would highly appreciate it if someone could help me out. I'm working with React for 1 month now and currently working on a Slider. I need some help, I am trying to add a class "first" and "last" for each slide dynamically. 
I have a Click event **PrevSlide** and **NextSlide** which will slide to the next and previous slide. However, if I reach the first or last slide I would like to add a class to the Prev/Next button. Instead, it's now adding the same class to all the slides on render. Also, how can I add the current Active ClassName on Click?

Can someone explain to me how to do this? Thanks in advance! so I can learn from this.

My code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

// Components
import QuizSlide from '../Slider/Slide';
import LeftArrow from '../Arrows/LeftArrow';
import RightArrow from '../Arrows/RightArrow';

// Import Pictures
import Slide1 from 'images/slider/1.jpeg';
import Slide2 from 'images/slider/2.jpeg';
import Slide3 from 'images/slider/3.jpeg';
import Slide4 from 'images/slider/4.jpeg';
import Slide5 from 'images/slider/5.jpeg';

// App Styles
import 'sass/root.scss';

export default class QuizSlider extends Component {

    // Constructor
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            currentIndex: 0,
            translateValue: 0,
            data: [
                {
                    content: 'Slide show 1',
                    image: `${Slide1}`
                },

                {
                    content: 'Slide show 2',
                    image: `${Slide2}`
                },

                {
                    content: 'Slide show 3',
                    image: `${Slide3}`
                },

                {
                    content: 'Slide show 4',
                    image: `${Slide4}`
                },

                {
                    content: 'Slide show 5',
                    image: `${Slide5}`
                }
            ]
        }
    }

    // Functions
    PrevSlide = () => {
        if(this.state.currentIndex === 0) {
          return this.setState({
            currentIndex: 0,
            translateValue: 0
          });
        }

        // This will not run if we met the if condition above
        this.setState(PrevState => ({
            currentIndex: PrevState.currentIndex - 1,
            translateValue: PrevState.translateValue + (this.slideWidth())
        }));        
    }

    NextSlide = () => {
        // Exiting the method early if we are at the end of the images array.
        // We also want to reset currentIndex and translateValue, so we return
        // to the first image in the array.
        if(this.state.currentIndex === this.state.data.length - 1) {
          return this.setState({
            currentIndex: 0,
            translateValue: 0
          });
        }

        // This will not run if we met the if condition above
        this.setState(NextState => ({
            currentIndex: NextState.currentIndex + 1,
            translateValue: NextState.translateValue + -(this.slideWidth())
        }));
    }

    slideWidth = () => {
        return document.querySelector('.QuizSlide').clientWidth
    }   

    // Render
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="QuizSlider">

                <div
                  className="slider-wrapper" 
                  style={{
                    transform: `translateX(${this.state.translateValue}px)`,
                    transition: 'transform ease-out 0.45s'
                  }}
                >

                {
                    this.state.data.map((props, index) => (
                        <QuizSlide key={index} image={props.image}  />
                    ))
                }  

                </div>

                <LeftArrow PrevSlide={this.PrevSlide} />
                <RightArrow NextSlide={this.NextSlide} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: One thing I'm confused about: the `div` with the `slider-wrapper` class currently wraps all of the images (as create by the `this.state.data.map`). Instead of a `.map`, did you mean to display a single image there based on the value of `currentIndex`?

Answer (score 0):

you can conditionally render the first, last, and active classes in the render as you map over your data

[here's an example to check out](https://codesandbox.io/s/9z0jw283wo) with notes to help explain what's going on. open dev tool to see the classes rendering